# A shorter way for multiple str_replace

Tags: php

```
$a = 'hello_world.php';
```

I need `HELLO WORLD`

```
$a = str_replace('.php', '', $a);
$a = str_replace('_', ' ', $a);
$a = strtoupper($a);
```

This works but - is there a shorter way?

Comment: At least, please, read [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) manual page. It supports arrays

Comment: @AlmaDo, I think you have something to learn from `Rikesh`, for example.

Comment: If that's about snatching comments, then - sure, I should. Nevermind - it's not my intention to make you willing to learn. It's just about SO question quality. Nothing personal

Comment: @AlmaDo, saying that a question has bad question quality without saying what is bad in the question is not the standard SO behavior quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrays as arguments in [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$a = strtoupper(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), array('', ' '), $a));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) with arrays:

```
echo strtoupper(str_replace(['.php', '_'], ['', ' '], $a));
```

Note that the above statement uses the [short array syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-96), which is only available on PHP 5.4+. If you're using an older PHP version, you'll have to use the `array(...)` syntax:

```
echo strtoupper(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), array('', ' '), $a));
```

If the filename extension isn't known beforehand, you could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\w+)\..*/i', function ($m) {
    return strtoupper(str_replace('_', ' ', $m[1]));
}, $a);
```

Comment: Why? As mentioned: str_replace + arrays. Also it's needed _whole_ string in upper case

Comment: @AlmaDo: `str_replace()` wouldn't work if the extension, for example, isn't known beforehand.

Comment: **Also, `[ ]` are PHP 5.4 if I'm not mistaken?**

Comment: @Jimbo: Yeah, they're a [PHP 5.4+](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-96) feature.

Comment: Probably best put that in the post - I always do that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use strtr function and also use " instead of ' (apostrophe)

Comment: kmike, why `"` instead of `'` ?

Comment: Although in languages like Java where it *is* important to differentiate between `"` and `'` - this is *not* the case in PHP. Consistency is the most important thing.